# How to optimize a complex oracle query using pagination

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to get data from an oracle DB to paint some sort of matrix in an html table. The query I needed turned out to be very complex and slow, so I decided to implement pagination.

I followed many articles and posts, but the one I liked the most was this one: [On rownum and limiting results](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-rownum-and-limiting-results)

But it doesn't seem to work, the execution takes as long time as if there was no rows restriction, sometimes it even takes longer.

Please keep in mind than I'm new with oracle, I'm used to recent versions of MS SQL

Here's a brief example of what my query looks like:

```
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS(n) */ a.*, ROWNUM rnum FROM (
            WITH T1 AS (
                SELECT ... FROM VIEW_1
                INNER JOIN ...
                WHERE ...
                GROUP BY ...
            ),
            T2 AS (
                SELECT ... FROM VIEW_2
                INNER JOIN ...
                WHERE ...
                GROUP BY ...
            ),
            T3 AS (
                SELECT ... FROM VIEW_3
                LEFT JOIN ...
                WHERE ...
                GROUP BY ...
            )
            SELECT
                T1.LVL,
                T1.CRSE,
                T2.ID,
                T3.GRADE
            FROM T1
            INNER JOIN T2 ON ...

            LEFT JOIN T3 ON ...

            ORDER BY T2.ID DESC, T1.LVL, T1.CRSE) a
        WHERE ROWNUM <= (PAGE * 50))
    WHERE rnum >= ((PAGE-1) * 50);
```

My actual query is quite larger, and I mostly use views I don't have access to.

I don't know if the /*+ FIRST_ROWS(n) */ works like that... and also don't think I can set a variable there...

I was expecting the execution time to be much lower that without the ROWNUM check, but it just doesn't work, and I've read its because of the GROUP BY usage. Can someone please help me make my pagination faster?

EDIT:
Here's the EXPLAIN PLAN from my query, I hope it helps:

```
    Plan hash value: 3394899150

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                   | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                            |                             |  3950 |   648K|       | 17918   (1)| 00:03:36 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                                       |                             |  3950 |   648K|       | 17918   (1)| 00:03:36 |
|*  2 |   COUNT STOPKEY                             |                             |       |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    VIEW                                     |                             |  8424 |  1275K|       | 17918   (1)| 00:03:36 |
|   4 |     TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION               |                             |       |       |       |            |          |
|   5 |      LOAD AS SELECT                         | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6FD2_17D15EA9 |       |       |       |            |          |
|   6 |       HASH UNIQUE                           |                             |    36 |  2052 |       |   250   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|   7 |        VIEW                                 | PS_UAG_ISBI_MAT_VW          |    36 |  2052 |       |   249   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|*  8 |         HASH JOIN                           |                             |    36 |  3744 |       |   249   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|   9 |          NESTED LOOPS                       |                             |    34 |  2312 |       |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |           NESTED LOOPS                      |                             |    44 |  2312 |       |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  11 |            NESTED LOOPS                     |                             |     1 |    46 |       |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | PS_ACAD_PROG_TBL            |     1 |    29 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 13 |              INDEX SKIP SCAN                | PS1ACAD_PROG_TBL            |     1 |       |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 14 |             INDEX RANGE SCAN                | PS1ACAD_ORG_TBL             |     1 |    17 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 15 |            INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | PS2CRSE_OFFER               |    44 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 16 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | PS_CRSE_OFFER               |    33 |   726 |       |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  17 |          VIEW                               |                             | 12227 |   429K|       |   235   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|* 18 |           HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER             |                             | 12227 |   573K|       |   235   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|* 19 |            INDEX FAST FULL SCAN             | PS_CRSE_ATTRIBUTES          |  7690 |   135K|       |    98   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|  20 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL                | PS_CRSE_CATALOG             | 12227 |   358K|       |   136   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|  21 |      LOAD AS SELECT                         | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6FD3_17D15EA9 |       |       |       |            |          |
|  22 |       VIEW                                  |                             |   682 | 36146 |       |  1091   (1)| 00:00:14 |
|* 23 |        HASH JOIN                            |                             |   682 | 41602 |       |  1091   (1)| 00:00:14 |
|* 24 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL                   | TYM_TRAYECTORIA             |   682 | 17050 |       |   513   (1)| 00:00:07 |
|  25 |         INDEX FAST FULL SCAN                | PS0PERSONAL_DATA            |   255K|  8985K|       |   577   (1)| 00:00:07 |
|  26 |      LOAD AS SELECT                         | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6FD4_17D15EA9 |       |       |       |            |          |
|  27 |       HASH GROUP BY                         |                             |   107 |  1605 |       | 16164   (1)| 00:03:14 |
|  28 |        VIEW                                 |                             |   107 |  1605 |       | 16163   (1)| 00:03:14 |
|* 29 |         HASH JOIN                           |                             |   107 |  2461 |       | 16163   (1)| 00:03:14 |
|  30 |          VIEW                               |                             |   682 |  5456 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  31 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6FD3_17D15EA9 |   682 | 36146 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  32 |          VIEW                               | PS_UAG_ISBI_CAL_VW          |  6411 | 96165 |       | 16160   (1)| 00:03:14 |
|  33 |           SORT UNIQUE                       |                             |  6411 |  7004K|  1960K| 16160   (1)| 00:03:14 |
|  34 |            UNION-ALL                        |                             |       |       |       |            |          |
|* 35 |             HASH JOIN                       |                             |  6342 |  1839K|       | 15289   (1)| 00:03:04 |
|* 36 |              INDEX FAST FULL SCAN           | PS_CRSE_ATTRIBUTES          |  7690 |   135K|       |    98   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|* 37 |              HASH JOIN                      |                             |  4943 |  1346K|       | 15191   (1)| 00:03:03 |
|* 38 |               HASH JOIN                     |                             |  4943 |  1168K|       | 10790   (1)| 00:02:10 |
|  39 |                INDEX FAST FULL SCAN         | PS1TERM_TBL                 |  1256 | 31400 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 40 |                HASH JOIN                    |                             |  4943 |  1047K|       | 10786   (1)| 00:02:10 |
|  41 |                 INDEX FAST FULL SCAN        | PS0CRSE_CATALOG             | 12227 |   358K|       |    31   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 42 |                 HASH JOIN                   |                             |  4985 |   910K|       | 10755   (1)| 00:02:10 |
|  43 |                  TABLE ACCESS FULL          | PS_ACAD_ORG_TBL             |   549 | 23058 |       |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 44 |                  HASH JOIN                  |                             |  5297 |   750K|  2856K| 10748   (1)| 00:02:09 |
|  45 |                   TABLE ACCESS FULL         | PS_CLASS_TBL                | 52112 |  2239K|       |   650   (1)| 00:00:08 |
|* 46 |                   HASH JOIN                 |                             |   100K|  9893K|       |  9422   (1)| 00:01:54 |
|  47 |                    TABLE ACCESS FULL        | PS_ACAD_PROG_TBL            |   313 | 18467 |       |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 48 |                    TABLE ACCESS FULL        | PS_STDNT_ENRL               |   986K|    39M|       |  9414   (1)| 00:01:53 |
|  49 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL             | PS_PERSONAL_DATA            |   255K|  9235K|       |  4400   (1)| 00:00:53 |
|  50 |             NESTED LOOPS                    |                             |    69 | 19596 |       |   462   (1)| 00:00:06 |
|  51 |              NESTED LOOPS                   |                             |    69 | 19596 |       |   462   (1)| 00:00:06 |
|* 52 |               HASH JOIN                     |                             |    69 | 17043 |       |   324   (1)| 00:00:04 |
|* 53 |                HASH JOIN                    |                             |    69 | 15318 |       |   320   (1)| 00:00:04 |
|* 54 |                 HASH JOIN                   |                             |   105 | 21420 |       |   222   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|* 55 |                  HASH JOIN                  |                             |   101 | 17574 |       |   191   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|* 56 |                   HASH JOIN                 |                             |   101 | 14443 |       |    88   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|* 57 |                    HASH JOIN                |                             |   314 | 31714 |       |    12   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  58 |                     TABLE ACCESS FULL       | PS_ACAD_PROG_TBL            |   313 | 18467 |       |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  59 |                     TABLE ACCESS FULL       | PS_ACAD_ORG_TBL             |   549 | 23058 |       |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  60 |                    VIEW                     |                             |  7540 |   309K|       |    76   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 61 |                     HASH JOIN               |                             |  7540 |   493K|       |    76   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  62 |                      TABLE ACCESS FULL      | PS_TRNS_CRSE_SCH            |   597 | 16119 |       |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  63 |                      TABLE ACCESS FULL      | PS_TRNS_CRSE_DTL            |  7540 |   294K|       |    70   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  64 |                   TABLE ACCESS FULL         | PS_CRSE_OFFER               | 12227 |   370K|       |   102   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|  65 |                  INDEX FAST FULL SCAN       | PS0CRSE_CATALOG             | 12227 |   358K|       |    31   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 66 |                 INDEX FAST FULL SCAN        | PS_CRSE_ATTRIBUTES          |  7690 |   135K|       |    98   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|  67 |                INDEX FAST FULL SCAN         | PS1TERM_TBL                 |  1256 | 31400 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 68 |               INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | PS_PERSONAL_DATA            |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  69 |              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | PS_PERSONAL_DATA            |     1 |    37 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 70 |      SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY                  |                             |  8424 |  1628K|  1736K|   413   (1)| 00:00:05 |
|* 71 |       HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                 |                             |  8424 |  1628K|       |    46   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|  72 |        VIEW                                 |                             |   108 |  2700 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  73 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL                   | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6FD4_17D15EA9 |   108 |  1620 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 74 |        HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                |                             |    78 | 13494 |       |    44   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|  75 |         VIEW                                |                             |    26 |   390 |       |    24   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|  76 |          HASH GROUP BY                      |                             |    26 |   702 |       |    24   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|  77 |           VIEW                              |                             |    47 |  1269 |       |    24   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|  78 |            HASH GROUP BY                    |                             |    47 |  2256 |       |    24   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|* 79 |             HASH JOIN OUTER                 |                             |    47 |  2256 |       |    23   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 80 |              HASH JOIN OUTER                |                             |    47 |  1081 |       |    21   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  81 |               VIEW                          |                             |    36 |   360 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  82 |                TABLE ACCESS FULL            | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6FD2_17D15EA9 |    36 |  2052 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  83 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL             | PS_RQ_GRP_DETL_TBL          |  2702 | 35126 |       |    19   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  84 |              VIEW                           |                             |   108 |  2700 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  85 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL             | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6FD4_17D15EA9 |   108 |  1620 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 86 |         HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER               |                             |    78 | 12324 |       |    20   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|  87 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | PS_UAG_PRECARG_SUBJECT      |    12 |   168 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 88 |          HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER              |                             |    78 | 11232 |       |    17   (6)| 00:00:01 |
|  89 |           VIEW                              |                             |     1 |    20 |       |    12   (9)| 00:00:01 |
|  90 |            HASH GROUP BY                    |                             |     1 |    30 |       |    12   (9)| 00:00:01 |
|  91 |             VIEW                            | PS_UAG_OFERCRSE_VW          |     1 |    30 |       |    12   (9)| 00:00:01 |
|  92 |              HASH UNIQUE                    |                             |     1 |   213 |       |    12   (9)| 00:00:01 |
|  93 |               NESTED LOOPS OUTER            |                             |     1 |   213 |       |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  94 |                NESTED LOOPS OUTER           |                             |     1 |   177 |       |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  95 |                 NESTED LOOPS OUTER          |                             |     1 |   139 |       |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 96 |                  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| PS_CLASS_TBL                |     1 |    69 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 97 |                   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | PSDCLASS_TBL                |     1 |       |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  98 |                  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| PS_CLASS_MTG_PAT            |     1 |    70 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 99 |                   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | PS_CLASS_MTG_PAT            |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 100 |                 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | PS_CLASS_INSTR              |     1 |    38 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*101 |                  INDEX RANGE SCAN           | PS_CLASS_INSTR              |     1 |       |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 102 |                TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | PS_PERSONAL_DATA            |     1 |    36 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*103 |                 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | PS_PERSONAL_DATA            |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 104 |           VIEW                              |                             |    78 |  9672 |       |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*105 |            HASH JOIN                        |                             |    78 | 10140 |       |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 106 |             VIEW                            |                             |    36 |  2988 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 107 |              TABLE ACCESS FULL              | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6FD2_17D15EA9 |    36 |  2052 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 108 |             VIEW                            |                             |   682 | 32054 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 109 |              TABLE ACCESS FULL              | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6FD3_17D15EA9 |   682 | 36146 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("RNUM">=0)
   2 - filter(ROWNUM<=3950)
   8 - access("D"."CRSE_ID"="C"."CRSE_ID")
  13 - access("A"."ACAD_PROG"='LMC09')
       filter("A"."ACAD_PROG"='LMC09')
  14 - access("B"."INSTITUTION"="A"."INSTITUTION" AND "B"."ACAD_ORG"="A"."ACAD_ORG")
  15 - access("C"."SUBJECT"="A"."ACAD_PLAN")
  16 - filter("C"."INSTITUTION"="A"."INSTITUTION")
  18 - access("E"."CRSE_ID"(+)="D"."CRSE_ID")
  19 - filter("E"."CRSE_ATTR"(+)='0003')
  23 - access("PERS"."EMPLID"="TRA"."EMPLID")
  24 - filter("TRA"."STRM"='1835' AND "TRA"."ACAD_PLAN"='LMC09')
  29 - access("A2"."EMPLID"="CAL"."EMPLID")
  35 - access("F"."CRSE_ID"="E"."CRSE_ID")
  36 - filter("F"."CRSE_ATTR"='0003')
  37 - access("B"."EMPLID"="A"."EMPLID")
  38 - access("H"."INSTITUTION"="A"."INSTITUTION" AND "H"."ACAD_CAREER"="A"."ACAD_CAREER" AND "H"."STRM"="A"."STRM")
  40 - access("E"."CRSE_ID"="C"."CRSE_ID")
  42 - access("G"."INSTITUTION"="A"."INSTITUTION" AND "G"."ACAD_ORG"="D"."ACAD_ORG")
  44 - access("C"."INSTITUTION"="A"."INSTITUTION" AND "C"."ACAD_CAREER"="A"."ACAD_CAREER" AND "C"."STRM"="A"."STRM" AND 
              "C"."CLASS_NBR"="A"."CLASS_NBR" AND "C"."SESSION_CODE"="A"."SESSION_CODE")
  46 - access("D"."INSTITUTION"="A"."INSTITUTION" AND "D"."ACAD_CAREER"="A"."ACAD_CAREER" AND 
              "D"."ACAD_PROG"="A"."ACAD_PROG")
  48 - filter("A"."STDNT_ENRL_STATUS"='E')
  52 - access("H"."INSTITUTION"="A"."INSTITUTION" AND "H"."ACAD_CAREER"="A"."ACAD_CAREER" AND 
              "H"."STRM"="A"."ARTICULATION_TERM")
  53 - access("F"."CRSE_ID"="E"."CRSE_ID")
  54 - access("E"."CRSE_ID"="C"."CRSE_ID")
  55 - access("C"."INSTITUTION"="A"."INSTITUTION" AND "C"."ACAD_CAREER"="A"."ACAD_CAREER" AND "C"."CRSE_ID"="A"."CRSE_ID")
  56 - access("D"."INSTITUTION"="A"."INSTITUTION" AND "D"."ACAD_CAREER"="A"."ACAD_CAREER" AND 
              "D"."ACAD_PROG"="A"."ACAD_PROG" AND "G"."INSTITUTION"="A"."INSTITUTION")
  57 - access("G"."ACAD_ORG"="D"."ACAD_ORG")
  61 - access("B"."EMPLID"="A"."EMPLID" AND "B"."ACAD_CAREER"="A"."ACAD_CAREER" AND "B"."INSTITUTION"="A"."INSTITUTION" 
              AND "B"."MODEL_NBR"="A"."MODEL_NBR")
  66 - filter("F"."CRSE_ATTR"='0003')
  68 - access("B"."EMPLID"="A"."EMPLID")
  70 - filter(ROWNUM<=3950)
  71 - access("C3"."CRSE_ID"(+)="from$_subquery$_019"."CRSE_ID" AND "C3"."EMPLID"(+)="from$_subquery$_019"."EMPLID")
  74 - access("R3"."EMPLID"(+)="from$_subquery$_019"."EMPLID" AND 
              "R3"."RQRMNT_GROUP"(+)="from$_subquery$_019"."RQRMNT_GROUP")
       filter("from$_subquery$_019"."RQRMNT_GROUP"<>CASE  WHEN ("R3"."RQRMNT_GROUP"(+) IS NOT NULL) THEN ' ' ELSE ' ' END )
  79 - access("REQ"."CRSE_ID"="C2"."CRSE_ID"(+))
  80 - access("REQ"."RQRMNT_GROUP"(+)="M2"."RQRMNT_GROUP")
       filter("M2"."RQRMNT_GROUP"<>CASE  WHEN ("REQ"."RQRMNT_GROUP"(+) IS NOT NULL) THEN ' ' ELSE ' ' END )
  86 - access("DTL"."CRSE_ID"(+)="M3"."CRSE_ID" AND "A3"."IDTRAYECTORIA"=TO_NUMBER("DTL"."ID_TRAYECTORIA"(+)))
  88 - access("H3"."CRSE_ID"(+)="from$_subquery$_019"."CRSE_ID")
  96 - filter("A"."SESSION_CODE"='ORD' AND "A"."CLASS_STAT"='A')
  97 - access("A"."SUBJECT"='LMC09' AND "A"."STRM"='1853')
  99 - access("B"."CRSE_ID"(+)="A"."CRSE_ID" AND "B"."CRSE_OFFER_NBR"(+)="A"."CRSE_OFFER_NBR" AND "B"."STRM"(+)='1853' AND 
              "B"."SESSION_CODE"(+)='ORD' AND "B"."CLASS_SECTION"(+)="A"."CLASS_SECTION")
 101 - access("C"."CRSE_ID"(+)="B"."CRSE_ID" AND "C"."CRSE_OFFER_NBR"(+)="B"."CRSE_OFFER_NBR" AND "C"."STRM"(+)="B"."STRM" 
              AND "C"."SESSION_CODE"(+)="B"."SESSION_CODE" AND "C"."CLASS_SECTION"(+)="B"."CLASS_SECTION" AND 
              "C"."CLASS_MTG_NBR"(+)="B"."CLASS_MTG_NBR")
 103 - access("D"."EMPLID"(+)="C"."EMPLID")
 105 - access("M3"."ACAD_PLAN"="A3"."ACAD_PLAN")
```

EDIT 2, SOLUTION:
I Managed to find the indexes already configured for the table 'PS_STDNT_ENRL' using the following query:

```
SELECT
    index_owner, index_name, table_name, column_name, column_position
FROM DBA_IND_COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'PS_STDNT_ENRL'
ORDER BY
    index_owner,
    table_name,
    index_name,
    column_position;
```

And found the columns needed on my WHERE clause so that the index works. 
I modified my query and now its very fast.

Comment: Nobody here can help without more details.  You need to run an "explain plan" to see the query execution paths.  Take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#i17492)  when you get the results, edit the question text and post them  THanks,.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I added it, I hope its what you need

Comment: Yes. thanks.  You have a lot of full table scans. That is OK for small tables, but may be an issue on larger ones, and there is no index being used.  Stuff like S_STDNT_ENRL    986K is reading almost 1M rows.  You may need to add some indexes.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to get rid of those full scans. Thanks

Comment: @OldProgrammer Its done, I didn't know anything about indexes, I researched about them and modified my WHERE in many parts of my query. Now it is FAST. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

ROWNUM only limits the number of rows presented AFTER the query runs and returns ALL rows.  So it is still doing all of the work.

If t1.id is numeric, you can use MOD() to reduce the amount of work up front and easily chunk-up your results into as many sections as you desire.  By way of example, MOD() of 5 against t1.id would allow you to break the results up into 5 sections corresponding to MOD() results of 0,1,2,3,4.

```
SELECT MOD(/*t1.id*/1000,5) FROM dual;
```

In this manner you reduce the number of rows considered in your driving table (t1) so there is less data to be managed after the other tables are joined in.

It would look something like this:

```
    AND MOD(t1.id,5) =
    00  -- Partition 1
--  01  -- Partition 2
--  02  -- Partition 3
--  03  -- Partition 4
--  04  -- Partition 5
```